# Microsoft cognitive services face API expired and free version

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have a simple question.
Microsoft cognitive services face API has a free option. I am currently on my 30 days trial for it.
When the face API will expire (in 12 days), will it still be available to use using the free version ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Face API has free tier for 20 QPM and 30K queries per month. However, you will need keys from Azure portal: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.CognitiveServicesFace to go beyond 1 month. I presume you have trial keys from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/?api=face-api, which are meant for limited period only.